# What is going on with just installed shingles?

Tags: roof, shingles

I need all the help I can get. Textbook single female homeowner being scammed by roofers. New roof installed 3months ago. Why are the shingles looking like this already like this is incorrect right!?

These pics are taken in the second floor of very old garage. The blue at the top is how they covered my old exterior vent hole thing and they didn't put any type of venting in at all.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "The worst case that can cause shingle granule loss is if your roofing contractor has installed faulty shingles that are already damaged. This, however, is quite easy to spot since your roof will likely go bald after just a few weeks." https://www.waddleexteriors.com/granule-loss-on-new-shingles/

Comment: Most roofing contracts offer a guarantee of some sort, and would specify what class of shingle will be used.  You don't say why you think you're being scammed.  Have the roofers dismissed the issue as not a problem and refused to do anything about it?

Comment: The close up picture looks like something was dragged over the shingles and gouge some.

Comment: Yes the guarantee would come after I pay them in full. Which I have not bc the shingles looked like this immediately after installed and I dont get why I should have to pay them for that. They knew and saw exactly what they were doing. the shingles is just one of the many things I’ve found after hiring them to install new roof and siding. They refuse to listen to me/negotiate and threaten lien.  It is very difficult finding honest opinions on standard practices and I’ve been blown off bc no one wants their name involved. i have so many questions lol thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: how do i thank all of you for responding omg yes! thats what i said it looks like they opened their corona bottles with my roof lol

Comment: What percentage of the bill are you holding back? I hate to say, but if it’s low (like, 10-20%), they probably don’t give a damn. Lawyer up (not this stack, but there is a law stack) to avoid the lien.

Comment: my house and garage are smalllll. like single family upstate ny small. they want 60k for siding and roof smh. i offered them 30k for now they said nope all or mechanics lien.

Comment: Do you have a documented conversation about a change order to remedy the broken roof sheathing?

Comment: the contractor will not speak to me. i get at least 2 threatening letters a week demanding full pay. he does not know about the shingles,sheathing etc..he was never here to do or see the work and never returned for walk through. it was a group of others that did actual work. so i am collecting my list of what ive learned is subpar industry standards to use against them

Comment: how do you determine what to deduct/pay them for when all of it needs to be redone correctly. thats what i dont understand who gets to calculate that amount bc i dont think they deserve anything i could have done this awful work myself

Comment: I’m on the brink of voting to close, as this is more of a legal issue. The work is substandard, as any shingle manufacturer’s warranty would almost certainly specify adequate roof decking. If they can prove you refused a change order, then you’re screwed. Get quotes from others to establish what part of the contract you won’t pay.

Comment: The blue you can see from the inside isn't covering "venting" it's covering broken roof sheathing. Unless that happens to be some sort of hard board, like OSB that happened to be painted blue, they should have replaced the broken boards. It does look like there's a gable-end vent that's been covered over, though that may not have been open when they started.

Comment: Is the company licensed, insured, bonded? If so, contact the state licensing board and have a _polite_ conversation with them about what you should do. Ask if they have an inspector who would come look at the workmanship of one of their licensed companies. You may have to pay a bit for the inspection, but if it's deemed they've done substandard work, they'll come back to make it right or risk loosing their license.

Comment: Your best bet is to approach a surveyor, and perhaps (or even through them) the independent opinions of professional roofing companies. They won't solve your problem, but their opinion would be first step in any formal dispute.

Comment: A ridge vent is often a required element for the shingle company to honor the warranty...I don't see one here.